# AspNet ViewState piece showing on the page with Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, viewstate

Im not sure why is this happening but there is a piece of viewstate being shown on the top of my page with its closing tag.

I believe is just happening when there is some javascript code in the page, but is quite odd because has nothing to do with the ViewState at all.

Anybody knows anything about this?

Thanks,
Leonardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any chance you could provide the offending code snippet and what *precisely* gets displayed on the page that shouldn't?

Based on what's been provided in the OP, it could be as simple as improperly nested tags

e.g.

```
<tag1><tag2></tag1></tag2>
```

Different browsers handle this problem differently, so it would come as no surprise that this produced unexpected behavior.

Similarly. different browsers also handle unclosed tags differently so watch out for that.